# Unir resultado de dos consultas en SQL Server sin repetir registros

Tags: sql-server, sql, base-de-datos

Estimados tengan un buen día, mi pregunta es la siguiente.

Quiero unir los resultado de dos consultas que coinciden en columnas y tipo de datos, como primera opción se me ocurrió un UNION, mi primera consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT      T1.ArrivalDate AS Llegada, T1.DepartureDate AS Salida, T3.AccountNo AS Folio,
            T6.RoomNo AS Habitacion, T2.GuestTotal AS Huespedes, T7.Name AS Tarifa
FROM        obooGuest AS T1 INNER JOIN
            obooBooking AS T2 ON T2.ID_Booking = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            oaccAccount AS T3 ON T3.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            otrnTrnAccount AS T5 ON T5.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            prCode AS T7 ON T1.ID_RateCode = T7.ID_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
            rmRoom AS T6 ON T6.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
UNION ALL
SELECT        T2.StartDate AS Llegada, T2.EndDate AS Salida, T2.AccountNo AS Folio, Habitacion = NULL, T2.GuestTotal AS Huespedes, T4.Name AS Tarfia
FROM            prCode AS T4 INNER JOIN
                         oaccTemplate AS T3 ON T4.ID_Code = T3.ID_RateCode RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         obooGrp AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         V_GrpAndAllot AS T2 ON T2.ID_GrpAllot = T1.ID_Grp ON T3.ID_Template = T1.ID_Grp
```

Y el resultado de la consulta es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi segunda consulta:

```
SELECT (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty) AS Llegada, (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty) AS Salida, T1.AccountNo, 'NA' AS Habitacion, '0' AS Huespedes, 'NA' AS Tarifa
FROM oaccAccount AS T1
```

Resultados de la segunda consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que quiero filtrar los registros de mi segunda consulta, en la columna "Folio" hay registros que ya están en la primera consulta y quiero descartarlos para que no se repita en ninguna ocasión el número de folio y los registros que conserven sean los de la primera consulta y descarte los que vengan repetidos de la segunda.

Comment: En caso de que los registros duplicados coincidan  en todos los campos basta con sustituir UNION ALL por UNION, prueba y nos comentas.

Comment: En realidad el único campo donde coinciden es en la columna de Folio, en caso de la segunda es AccountNo, pero ya en la versión final del script le puse también el alias de Folio para que tuvieran el mismo nombre. En resumen, solo esa columna es donde coinciden los datos, que ese número es un identificador de cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque hay varias formas de afrontar esto, la que mas me gusta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT      T1.ArrivalDate AS Llegada, T1.DepartureDate AS Salida, T3.AccountNo AS Folio,
            T6.RoomNo AS Habitacion, T2.GuestTotal AS Huespedes, T7.Name AS Tarifa
FROM        obooGuest AS T1 INNER JOIN
            obooBooking AS T2 ON T2.ID_Booking = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            oaccAccount AS T3 ON T3.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            otrnTrnAccount AS T5 ON T5.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            prCode AS T7 ON T1.ID_RateCode = T7.ID_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
            rmRoom AS T6 ON T6.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
UNION ALL
SELECT        T2.StartDate AS Llegada, T2.EndDate AS Salida, T2.AccountNo AS Folio, Habitacion = NULL, T2.GuestTotal AS Huespedes, T4.Name AS Tarfia
FROM            prCode AS T4 INNER JOIN
                         oaccTemplate AS T3 ON T4.ID_Code = T3.ID_RateCode RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         obooGrp AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         V_GrpAndAllot AS T2 ON T2.ID_GrpAllot = T1.ID_Grp ON T3.ID_Template = T1.ID_Grp
WHERE T3.AccountNo not in
(
SELECT      Folio
FROM        obooGuest AS T1 INNER JOIN
            obooBooking AS T2 ON T2.ID_Booking = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            oaccAccount AS T3 ON T3.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            otrnTrnAccount AS T5 ON T5.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
            prCode AS T7 ON T1.ID_RateCode = T7.ID_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
            rmRoom AS T6 ON T6.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
)
```

Simplemente a la segunda consulta le dices que no incluya los folios de la primera,

espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias pero fijate que como resultado de este query obtengo la misma cantidad de registros que los de mi primer consulta, sin sumar los de la segunda que no aparecen en la primera.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, cambié T2.AccountNo por T3.AccountNo, prueba a ver